# CORBA.NO_PERMISSION in glassfish 3.1.2.2 JDBC Security REALM

Tags: java, glassfish, jdbcrealm

please help me ti fix this...
what am I doing wrong?

```
09.02.2013 19:44:16 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'hello' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacemain.HelloRemote [Root exception is java.rmi.AccessException: CORBA NO_PERMISSION 0 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
```

CreateJDBCRealmUser class to create users in DB oracle 10g XE

```
package main;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class CreateJDBCRealmUser {
    private static final String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XE";
    private static final String userSql = "insert into users values(?, ?)";
    private static final String groupSql = "insert into groups values(?, ?)";



    private static final char[] HEXADECIMAL = { '0', '1', '2', '3',
        '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    private static String hashPassword(String password) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.reset();

        byte[] bytes = md.digest(password.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int low = (int)(bytes[i] & 0x0f);
            int high = (int)((bytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            sb.append(HEXADECIMAL[high]);
            sb.append(HEXADECIMAL[low]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String dbUser = "dbuser";
        String dbPassword = "dbpass";
        String user = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        String group = "admin";

        Class.forName(driver);
        String hPassword = hashPassword(password);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            jdbcUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
        PreparedStatement userStmt = conn.prepareStatement(userSql);
        userStmt.setString(1, user);
        userStmt.setString(2, hPassword);
        userStmt.executeUpdate();
        userStmt.close();

        PreparedStatement groupStmt = conn.prepareStatement(groupSql);
        groupStmt.setString(1, user);
        groupStmt.setString(2, group);
        groupStmt.executeUpdate();
        groupStmt.close();

        conn.close();
    }
}
```

HelloClient - its a JAVA app client

```
package main;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin;

public class HelloClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
        InitialContext ic = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "./auth.conf"); 
        ProgrammaticLogin pl = new ProgrammaticLogin();
        String spass = new String("admin");
        char pass[] = new char[spass.length()];
        pass = spass.toCharArray();
        pl.login("admin", pass);

        try {
            ic = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object obj = ic.lookup("hello");
        HelloRemote hello = (HelloRemote)obj;
        /*
        Call a business method, propagating the security context
        */
        String result;
        try {
        result = hello.hello();
        result = hello.helloNoPermit();
        }
        catch (javax.ejb.EJBException e) {
        result = e.getCausedByException().getMessage();
        }
        /* Print the return result from the business logic */
        System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HelloRemote - remote interface to EJB on client side, the same remote interface exists on server side/

```
package main;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface HelloRemote {
    String helloNoPermit();
    String hello();
}
```

Hello - its an implementation HelloRemote

```
package main;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Hello
 */
@Singleton(mappedName = "hello")
@DeclareRoles("admin")
public class Hello implements HelloRemote {

    @Resource 
    private SessionContext context;

    public Hello() {

    }

    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public String helloNoPermit(){

        String name = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        return name;

    }

    public String hello(){
        String name = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

auth.conf - config file

```
default {
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.ClientPasswordLoginModule required debug=false;
};
```

SQL DDL

```
create table USERS
(
  USER_NAME VARCHAR2(4000),
  USER_PASS VARCHAR2(4000)
)

create table GROUPS
(
  GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(4000),
  USER_NAME  VARCHAR2(4000)
)
```

and finaly GF 3.1.2.2 JDBC REALM config

```
Security Manager: V
Audit Logging:    V
Default Realm secureRealm:
Default Principal:
Default Principal Password:
JACC: default
Audit Modules: default
Default Principal To Role Mapping: V
Mapped Principal Class: 


Realm Name:secureRealm
Class Name: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
JAAS Context: secureRealm
JNDI: jdbc/secure
User Table:USERS
User Name Column:USER_NAME
Password Column:USER_PASS
Group Table:GROUPS
Group Table User Name Column:USER_NAME
Group Name Column:GROUP_NAME
Assign Groups:admin
Database User:
Database Password:
Digest Algorithm:MD5
Password Encryption Algorithm:MD5
Encoding: 
Charset:
```

sun-ejb-jar.xml

```
<sun-ejb-jar>
 <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <group-name>admin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <enterprise-beans />
</sun-ejb-jar>
```